# Varchar Length? SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

If I create a table in SQLite on Android:

```
create table [Table]
(
    [Column] varchar(32)
)
```

Testing my code I can store a string whose length is more than that, so using a limit is useless?

Does something happen internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [sqlite F.A.Q.](https://sqlite.org/faq.html):

> What is the maximum size of a VARCHAR in SQLite?
>
> SQLite does not enforce the length of a VARCHAR. You can declare a
>   VARCHAR(10) and SQLite will be happy to let you put 500 characters in
>   it. And it will keep all 500 characters intact - it never truncates.

From sqlite docs:

> [..] numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name
>   (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not impose
>   any length restrictions [..]

SQLite understands the column type of "VARCHAR(N)" to be the same as "TEXT", regardless of the value of N.

Comment: @Cris0334 It's sqlite FAQ that states it.. not me :D

Comment: @Cris0334 Yes, see SQLite FAQ ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did read about limits but didn't found anything about the varchar length

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html does not have `VARCHAR` as a data type, so does it work for android?

Comment: SQLite understands the column type of "VARCHAR(N)" to be the same as "TEXT", regardless of the value of N.